# How to diff multiple files across directories?

Tags: 10.04, diff

I am trying to find `diff`s between all files of same names across two copies of a directory (say a working and a backup). For example, I can `diff` two files of same name in both:

`> diff d1/f.cpp d2/f.cpp`

or I can find differences across the directories:

`> diff d1 d2`

but how can I find differences between the `*.cpp` files only?

`> diff d1/*.cpp d2/*.cpp`

does not seem to work (for obvious reasons).

[It is probably easy to solve with loops, but I am trying to find a more elegant way]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a shell loop that runs diff for each file, though this will not catch the cases where d2 contains a file, but d1 doesn't. It might be sufficient though.

```
for file in d1/*.cpp; do
    diff "$file" "d2/${file##*/}"
done
```

Or all on one line:

```
for file in d1/*.cpp; do diff "$file" "d2/${file##*/}"; done
```

The `${file##*/}` part is a special parameter expansion.

If the file variable contains `d1/hello.cpp`, then `"${file##*/}"` will expand to `hello.cpp` (the value of file, but with everything up to, and including, the last / removed).

So `"d2/${file##*/}"` will result in `d2/hello.cpp` and the resulting diff command is thus `diff d1/hello.cpp d2/hello.cpp`

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100 for more on string manipulations in bash.

On a side note, a version control system (such as subversion, git, mercurial etc...) would make this type of diffing much easier.

Comment: I think that of the two great answers, this on is more straight forward when there are multiple file types (although I mentioned in the question that I'm looking for a no-loops solution), so I accepted it. The one addition added is `echo "${file##*/}";` before the `diff` command, so one knows what files are actually being compared. Also, as mentioned in @Rinzwind's answer, this method does not cover the case were the file list is not exactly the same in both directories.

Answer (score 69):

`diff -qr {DIR1} {DIR2}` does all files in both directories.

- `q` shows only differences
- `r` does recursive. Leave it out if you do not need that

You can not tell `diff` directly to use wildcards but you can add:

```
-x PAT  --exclude=PAT
    Exclude files that match PAT.

-X FILE    --exclude-from=FILE
   Exclude files that match any pattern in FILE.
```

to exclude files. So if you only want `*.cpp` the easiest method is to create a textfile that lists all the files that are not `*.cpp`. You can do this with the following command:
`ls -I "*.cpp" > excluded_files` where the `-I "*.cpp"` argument ignores all the .cpp files. Note that the quotation marks are necessary.

Comment: You can add the `-s` flag to report when two files are the same if you want to feel a sense of reassurance and the number of files isn't too large `diff -sr {DIR1} {DIR2}`

Answer (score 7):

Some time after asking the question, I found out the [`meld`](http://meldmerge.org) diff utility, and am using it since then. This is a great piece of GUI based program that makes comparison and merge between files and directory a very easy task. It does two- or three-way compares.

Specifically, it answers my original question in that it shows you a color-coded comparison of the directory contents, and lets you compare specific files by a double-click on the file name.

If one needs more than a three-way comparison, then `gvimdiff` (based on the `vim` editor) is a great too as well that provides this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lightweight solution for that:

1. Set up this tiny plugin http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5309
2. Do `diff dir1 dir2 | vim -R -` at shell

It will add folds and side-by-side comparison for changed files.